# The app crashes when converting LocalDate to a string value with the format "yyyy-MM-dd", but works with "yyyy-MM-DD"

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, java-time

I'm trying to convert the returned date from a calendar into a string value, but it has an unwanted number. I've made a text that views the selected date value for today, and it's successfully printed in the wanted format (2024-03-09). But, when trying to view the (formattedString) value, it views (2024-03-69). This allows the API to view different data.
If anyone can help.

Edit: I'm trying to view football matches by date from Calendar.
The calling function in LaunchedEffect will be executed every time date changed by the Calendar.

The app is working perfectly with "yyyy-MM-DD" format but crashes with "yyyy-MM-dd" while running on a physical device or a virtual device.

[image]

```
val viewModel: MainViewModel = hiltViewModel()
val state = rememberUseCaseState()
val selectedDate = rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf<LocalDate?>(LocalDate.now()) }
val disabledDates = listOf(
        LocalDate.now().minusDays(30),
        LocalDate.now().plusDays(30),
)
val localDate = selectedDate.value //For reference
val formatter: DateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-DD")
val formattedString = localDate!!.format(formatter)
viewModel.saveDialogueDate(formattedString)
CalendarDialog(
        state = state,
        config = CalendarConfig(
               yearSelection = false,
               monthSelection = true,
               style = CalendarStyle.MONTH,
               disabledDates = disabledDates
        ),
        selection = CalendarSelection.Date { newDate ->
               selectedDate.value = newDate
               viewModel.saveCalendarClicked(true)
        }
)
```

Fetch API Data

```
@Composable
fun FetchTodayGamesData(
    mainViewModel: MainViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    val date = mainViewModel.dialogueDate.observeAsState().value!!
    if (mainViewModel.isClicked.value!!) {
        LaunchedEffect(key1 = null) {
            mainViewModel.getTodayMatches(
                date, 2023
            )
            mainViewModel.saveCalendarClicked(false)
        }
    }
    when (val state =
        mainViewModel.todayMatchesState.collectAsState().value
    ) {
        is TodayMatchesState.Empty -> {}
        is TodayMatchesState.Loading -> {}
        is TodayMatchesState.Error -> {}
        is TodayMatchesState.Success -> {
            TodayMatchesLazy(
                match = state.data.body()!!.response?.get(0)!!,
                matchesList = state.data.body()!!.response!!
            )
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
private var _todayMatchesState = MutableStateFlow<TodayMatchesState>(TodayMatchesState.Empty)
val todayMatchesState: StateFlow<TodayMatchesState> = _todayMatchesState

//Calendar Dialogue Date
private var _dialogueDate = MutableLiveData("")
val dialogueDate: LiveData<String> = _dialogueDate
private var _isClicked = MutableLiveData(true)
val isClicked: LiveData<Boolean> = _isClicked

fun saveCalendarClicked(isClicked: Boolean) {
      _isClicked.value = isClicked
}

fun saveDialogueDate(date: String) {
      _dialogueDate.value = date
}


fun getTodayMatches(date: String, season: Int) {
        _todayMatchesState.value = TodayMatchesState.Loading

        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {

            try {
                val todayMatchesResponse = todayMatchesRepository.getTodayMatches(date, season)
                _todayMatchesState.value = TodayMatchesState.Success(todayMatchesResponse)
            }
            catch (exception: HttpException) {
                _todayMatchesState.value = TodayMatchesState.Error("Something went wrong")
            }
            catch (exception: IOException) {
                _todayMatchesState.value = TodayMatchesState.Error("No internet connection")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `D` is day-of-year. I assume you want `d`, which is day-of-month. See [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter).

Comment: @Slaw
It gives the right values, but the app crashes every time with "dd" (App Not Responding) on a physical device.

Comment: Well, that seems like a different problem. You should provide a [mre] demonstrating that problem. And if the app is _crashing_ then there should be an error/stack trace that you can show us.

Comment: @Slaw
I've attached some code samples for a more clear explanation.

Comment: For `yyyy-MM-dd` format you can just use `localDate.toString()`. On the condition that `localDate` is not `null`. Or else `String.valueOf(localDate) `. Which value has `localDate` got when the crash happens?

Comment: @Anonymous
It worked fine at first with the current date, but when changing the date from the date picker, the selected date appears in text, but the app crashes.

Comment: I am not convinced that the crash has anything to do with the way you are formatting the date. It appears rather unrelated. That it happened with `dd` and not with `DD` could be a mere coincidence. Without a [mre] I don’t think we can help you further, I am sorry.